# How to overwrite previous FileWriter contents in Java

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

Hi I have 3 classes first and second class are computations and 3rd is where I save data from the first 2 classes to a text file.
I am attempting to reuse my method that writes calculated values from first and 2nd class into text file using FileWriter and BufferedWriter.

So i have something like this:
1) first class do calculations 
2) then use 3rd class writeDetected to save it in text file 
3) 2nd class do calculations 
4) then use 3rd class again using writeDetected

Everything is working except when I wanted to save the calculations I've done in 2nd class. The contents in text file contains the previous (first class calculations) + the second class calculation. What I wanted to have is a file that has the calculation of first class and another file with 2nd class calculations. Any ideas on how I should do this?

## edited:

Just to illustrate this: 

it should look something like this

class 1 {1,2,3,4}

class 2 {5,6,7,8}

What I have at the moment is

class 1 {1,2,3,4}

class 2 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

this is my code:

```
public void writeDetected(){
    Scanner getFileName = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Enter file name here for first class then after calculation of  
    // 2nd class enter another file name
    String getInp = getFileName.nextLine();
    try{
        FileWriter theFile = new FileWriter(getInp);
        BufferedWriter readBuf = new BufferedWriter (theFile); 
        String convDoubleToString;

        for (Double getVal: detected){
            convDoubleToString = getVal.toString();

            readBuf.write(convDoubleToString);
            readBuf.newLine();
        }

        readBuf.close();

    }

    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it matter? But to satisfy your curiosity its not am just learning how to program in java.

Comment: yes, it matters because people try to answer homework questions differently to help the person learn.  in your case, if you want to write to 2 different files, then you should use 2 different file names.  also, you should always close stream resources in finally blocks.

Comment: The source code I gave will ask for file name before saving any data and I have written the exact sequence above. So I don't have problem with naming each file differently. But thank you for replying i'll keep your advice in closing streams inside finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Sent the `path` from the `calling method as Argument` to the `Parameters of the called` `method`, in this way you can write your file content to whatever file you want (`Here` the called method will be `writeMyFile(String path)` )

Eg:

```
public void writeMyFile(String path){

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

File f = new File(path);

FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(f);

BufferedWriter br  = new BufferedWriter(fr);

while(true){  // its a continuos loop, so better handle it the way u want it

 br.write(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());

 } 
}
```

Comment: hi tnx for replying, just have a question what is while (b) here? is that suppose to be while (br)?

Comment: also what is the significance of boolean isDone here? i don't think it was used in the sample u gave me.

Comment: Sorry it was part of the loop controlling mechanism... it was my commandline program, the value of "b" controls the while loop. I forgot to remove it, as i took the snippet out of the my code base. Now i have removed it..so i hope now its ok

Answer (score 0):

I would add a string input variable to the method and pass in the filename to write to. That or you could create file objects and pass those as input parameters. I used a string myself and just passed in the file name to write to.

Comment: Hi logan thanks for replying, I don't have problem with naming the file class associated with each classes. But I just need to get rid of the contents previously written class because I am using the same method to write them. I edited my question with a sample to make it clearer.

Comment: Maybe after writedetected is finished you need to clear detected out. Is that some type of collection? Since that is what your for loop uses to write, the issue is that it still contains contents from the first class. Try clearing detected out after writing is done.

Comment: Detected is an ArrayList<Double> and yes I cleared it of previous values before I used the same write method to save class 2. So am suspecting that it has something to do with FileWriter or BufferedWriter and how to clear those buffered or saved files stored temporarily. I read in java documentation about flush() and close() that it saves this temporary files into memory. But I could be wrong so am hoping for any thoughts on this.

Comment: Add a system.out.printline to your for loop to show the value for each write. Print the same variable you use in the write command. That array has to contain the previous values. Your writers create new objects in your method so I do not think they are the problem.

Comment: yes am using clear() for detected. I am sure they don't have values coz I printed ArrayList detected and it only shows detected []. I printed it after saving the file computation for class 1.

Comment: Print each value before the write just to make sure. Maybe that loop is processing more than you expect. Also close theFile too, just in case thats causing this.

Comment: Do you only have 1 output file? If so, that is the problem. Java appends to a file if it exists already. Run f.remove() after declaring your file to delete it first.

Comment: Yes I also tried closing the Buffer and Writer and I also tried setting the boolean values of Writer still still the same. I have two files, refer to my sequence above numbered 1-4. I wrote different filename for each class that's why there is scanner inside write method. My only other option is just to create two Write Methods one for each class. But I really wanted to know how to reuse this write method because just in case I will have more than 100 of those classes. I can't possibly create 100 write method as well.

Comment: Add the system out println before the write. That will at least indicate where the file contents are coming from. Paste the results if you can. Ive done something similar to this, but i pass the filename and array as parameters to my write method. Then i create a file with the filename and write the array contents to it in my write method. Very similar to what you have.